# IE doesn't fire the change handler on Enter

Tags: internet-explorer-9

I have a jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/6MLy7/3/ - that changes a box width and height to values entered into input fields. For Firefox, Safari, and Chrome it's enough to just follow the new value with Enter.  That gets the change handler to fire. But IE10 doesn't see Enter.  You have to TAB to the other field to get the change handler to fire.

Is there a way with IE  to get Enter to fire an input change handler?

Thanks

```
$('input#box_W').change(function(e) {
    $('#box').width(this.value);        // set new width
})

$('input#box_H').change(function(e) {
    $('#box').height(this.value);       // set new height
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try firing the blur event on keypress (enter), which would then cause the change event (or then fire the change event directly if you prefer that).

```
$someParentControl.on('keypress', 'input,textarea', function (e) {
   if (e.which == 13 && !e.shiftKey) {
        $(this).blur();
        return false;
    }
});
```